# Cant refresh to bottom of page with javascript function containing url variables

Tags: javascript

I have a few cascading dropdowns on the bottom of my php page. Each time a user selects an option from the dropdown the following function is called to add the value of that option to my url variables. Currently the page refreshes to the top each time which is a huge problem. Normally I would use something like onCLick="window.location='page.htm#bottom';" to refresh to the bottom of the page but the below function stops working when I add the #bottom. Can someone help me adjust this function or give me other ideas that will refresh to the bottom of the page when the function is done.

```
function reload5(form){
if(document.getElementById('fda1').checked) {
 var fda = '1';
}else if(document.getElementById('fda0').checked) {
  var fda = '0';
}

var val=form.category.options[form.category.options.selectedIndex].value; 
var val2=form.subcat.options[form.subcat.options.selectedIndex].value;
var val3=form.subcat1.options[form.subcat1.options.selectedIndex].value;
var val4=form.subcat2.options[form.subcat2.options.selectedIndex].value;
var comp1=form.mname.options[form.mname.options.selectedIndex].text;
var itemnum=document.getElementById('item').value; 
var desc=document.getElementById('desc').value;
var quan=document.getElementById('quan').value;
var list=document.getElementById('list').value;
var uom=form.uom.options[form.uom.options.selectedIndex].text;
self.location='add_products.php#bottom?fda=' + fda + '&desc=' + desc + '&quan=' + quan + '&list=' + list + '&uom=' + uom + '&item=' + itemnum + '&cat=' + val + '&cat2=' + val2 + '&cat3=' + val3 + '&cat4=' + val4 + '&comp=' + comp1 ;
}
```

So this doesn't work: `self.location='add_products.php#bottom?fda=' + fda`

But this does       : `self.location='add_products.php?fda=' + fda`

Any idea where to put the #bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the hash must come after the query string at the end.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) article.  Try this... (I also cleaned up the code)

```
function reload5(form){
    var val=form.category.options[form.category.options.selectedIndex].value,
        val2=form.subcat.options[form.subcat.options.selectedIndex].value,
        val3=form.subcat1.options[form.subcat1.options.selectedIndex].value,
        val4=form.subcat2.options[form.subcat2.options.selectedIndex].value,
        comp1=form.mname.options[form.mname.options.selectedIndex].text,
        itemnum=document.getElementById('item').value,
        desc=document.getElementById('desc').value,
        quan=document.getElementById('quan').value,
        list=document.getElementById('list').value,
        uom=form.uom.options[form.uom.options.selectedIndex].text,
        fda;

    if(document.getElementById('fda1').checked) {
         fda = 1;
    } else if(document.getElementById('fda0').checked) {
         fda = 0;
    } else {
         fda = -1;
    }

    window.self.location.href = 'add_products.php?fda=' + fda + '&desc=' + desc + '&quan=' + quan + '&list=' + list + '&uom=' + uom + '&item=' + itemnum + '&cat=' + val + '&cat2=' + val2 + '&cat3=' + val3 + '&cat4=' + val4 + '&comp=' + comp1 + "#bottom";
}
```

What I don't understand is why you are not doing something with Ajax that would not cause the page to refresh at all.

Comment: Your a lifesaver. Thanks a bunch. Especially for cleaning up the code. Reason I haven't gone Ajax yet is I'm a newbie but I was really a newbie last year when I wrote this page. I could probably pull off now but just haven't gotten to it. Thanks again!